# slds-textarea Lightning Design System, How to make it display as read-only

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-design-system

I wish to use

```
<textarea id="textarea-id-01" class="slds-textarea" placeholder="enter my text here"/>
```

in a visualforce page which uses `<apex:slds />`

I wanted to know how I can make this read-only?

Comment: please refrain from asking for help in your posts. thanks

Comment: Well, to be more specific, putting things like 'Urgent', 'Please help', and 'Thanks in Advance' are discouraged here. 2 of the 3 seem to be mostly about keeping questions concise and on-topic (the question itself is a cry for help, and giving thanks is covered by being responsive, upvoting, and selecting a best answer). 'Urgent' seems to be discouraged because it's often thrown about by people who are in over their heads, want others to do their work for them, and/or don't give enough detail/enough time to understand what the issue is and provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textarea is an html tag, in slds it is only wrapped with other tags that are scoped to give it its styling, if you were to search (using google for example) only for the textarea tag, you would quickly find that it has a readonly attribute as specified [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_readonly.asp).

and can be set as follows:

```
    <textarea readonly>
        At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. 
        We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
    </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set text area to readonly

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/textarea

Adjust the variant to include readonly attribute, you should get the html for textarea with readonly.

Comment: Both responses could marked as answer but I can only pick one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: your call wins at the end of the day, this was another opportunity to learn as usual :)